# Solve equation using Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve this equation using Mathematica:

$$
    4^x -18^x-8=0
$$

I tried this code and it didn't work:

```
Solve[4^x-18^x-8==0,x]
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you read the error message? "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."

Comment: There are no real solutions as 4^x - 18^x < 1 for real x. Do you want a complex answer?

Comment: Yes this was the error message

Comment: Yes complex answers are also fine

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @Sadisharandinu, Try to see and find the roots (whether Real or Complex) using Contour plot: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194654/44142

Answer (score 14):

You just need to add a domain restriction. For example:

```
Solve[4^x - 18^x - 8 == 0 && Abs[x] < 10, x] //N
```

> {{x -> 0.655338 - 9.68327 I}, {x -> 0.655338 + 9.68327 I}, {x -> 
>      0.682744 - 5.32247 I}, {x -> 0.682744 + 5.32247 I}, {x -> 
>      0.712648 - 0.969253 I}, {x -> 0.712648 + 0.969253 I}, {x -> 
>      0.742883 - 3.37599 I}, {x -> 0.742883 + 3.37599 I}, {x -> 
>      0.771278 + 7.71356 I}, {x -> 0.771278 - 7.71356 I}}

*(I used [`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N) to convert the exact values (which are [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root) objects) into complex number)*. You can also use [`Re`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Re) and [`Im`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Im):

```
Solve[4^x - 18^x - 8 == 0 && 0<Re[x]<10 && 10<Im[x]<20, x] //N
```

> {{x -> 0.615189 + 18.4231 I}, {x -> 0.632332 + 14.0506 I}, {x -> 
>      0.795925 + 12.0444 I}, {x -> 0.815342 + 16.3697 I}}

Answer (score 11):

If you can live with numerical complex-valued solutions,

```
FindRoot[4^x - 18^x - 8 == 0, {x, I}]
(*    {x -> 0.712648 + 0.969253 I}    *)

FindRoot[4^x - 18^x - 8 == 0, {x, -I}]
(*    {x -> 0.712648 - 0.969253 I}    *)
```

There are infinitely many more solutions. To look for them, you could use starting points gathered from a `DensityPlot` or similar.